# Create a surface and bind it to a non-visible canvas

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Is it possible to draw on a canvas that can then be used by MediaCodec? I don't want the canvas to be displayed and I don't want to use OpenGL ES. So using a SurfaceView would be out of the question. I would like to think that it must be possible to create a memory-only canvas and draw on it and then feed that into the MediaCodec. It isn't clear to me how to create a canvas that is also bound to a surface. The docs on MediaCodec indicate that a surface can be created using the createInputSurface method, but it clearly states:

> The Surface must be rendered with a hardware-accelerated API, such as OpenGL ES.

So what other way is there to create a surface and bind it to a canvas?